# Linking Spotfire to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, connection, spotfire

I hope you can help. I have a pretty big Excel file stored on my local drive that is linked to my Sharepoint model.

Because this excel file is so large it has taken up a lot of space so I have placed this file and a second file "World Map" in my Sharepoint.

See Pic 1

Pic 1

[image]

The current location of the Excel file is here `H:\TOV Storage Folder\EFPIA_TOV All_Master_Master.xlsx`

and the current World map is stored here `H:\WorldMap\World_Countries.shp`

What I would like to do is replace these files with their equivalents in Sharepoint but I keep getting the same error when I try to do so.

See Pic 2

The link that I am placing into the OData Connection is this

```
http://teamspace.merck.com/sites/emea_efpia/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Femea%5Fefpia%2FShared%20Documents%2FBET%2FTOV%20Master&FolderCTID=0x012000FA7F4E9565D6274DAF9E871EA008299B&View={B6EF0397-E24C-49DF-92EF-CB7015B60539}
```

But I keep getting the error pop up in Pic 2. 
Can anyone help me solve this issue? 
I simply wish to replace the files on my H drive feeding my Spotfire model to the ones in Sharepoint.

Pic 2

[image]

Comment: At first glance the [URL doesn't look right](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spc/4.0.0/doc/html/odata/odata_loading_data_from_sharepoint.htm). Have you altered it?

Comment: Hi again Scsimon :-) thanks for getting in touch.  no I have not altered it. I simply just copied the link you can see in the browser/search area of the top left area of Pic 1 and then pasted it into the Spotfire area.

Comment: Ah. I'd definitely give that a shot then! I know the ODATA can be tricky. Check that link i posted above. It's hard to tell what your's should be changed to but if you right click on the file and view it's absolute path I'd start with that versus what the aspx returned.

Answer (score 1):

I do this a lot with Spotfire; Try the OData link:
http://teamspace.merck.com/sites/emea_efpia/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

You will likely need to include authentication details for your active directory.

You can also try following that link in internet explorer/chrome to see the XML (if you get page not found someone has customised something and it wont work).